# What are ways to provide a Configurable script in a react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app which is for handling multiple dashboards with custom widgets. So far, these widgets can be configured only using JSON served from a rest API and it renders the entire dashboard. the config looks something like below.

```
{
 widgets: [
 {
   widgetId: "nanoid",
   widgetType: "LINE_CHART",
   dataFields: { },
   dataSource: { },
   widgetConfig: { }
   ...
 }
 ]
}
```

The entire point of going with JSON through rest API is to have a UI to edit, create and manage the dashboards.

This has limitations and one of them is, not all customization can be accomodated into this JSON without increasing the complexity.

What I am looking for is to have a customized editable script that has the widget instance passed in as a param to extend its customization without increasing the component complexity (as there can be n dashboards, its difficult to have a component with n number of functionality OR to have n components).

The requirement is to store the script in a DB and fetch the script in the frontend to execute it within the widget.

Any other possible solutions Please?

Ideas brainstormed:

1. I don't want to go with stringified functions and `eval`ing in the client side as it may pose security risks (if im not wrong)
2. Injecting the script in the browser wont have access to the widget scope directly (which is required in my case).